# Restrict joined/combined words using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a situation where I am calculating words in a textarea, However I noticed that a user could easily join words together and be accounted for as one. Is there a way to separate the words?

Comment: Not easily. You could potentially use a dictionary, but then you have the issue of valid compound words. It's far easier to restrict by characters instead of words, if possible.

Comment: Its really not clear what you want, but if you need to split the words in a textarea use `.split(' ')`

Comment: Right now I agree with you @RoryMcCrossan a dictionary is the closet idea to a solution.